# Replacing Multiple column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know how to a replace a column value in a dataframe

```
df.loc[df.column_name >= value,'column_name'] = value
```

My dataframe looks like this

```html
col1 col2 col3 upto col1000
1 2 1 1
0 3 1 1
0 1 0 1
1 1 0 0
2 1 2 2
1 0 2 2
2 0 4 4
2 2 1 4
1 2 1 2
```

I want to replace all the values in a column greater than 1 and replace them with 1. Is there a easier way to do that Or we need to write for loop for that??

Comment: What've you tried so far? And what exactly is the parameter you plan using to replace the values?

Comment: Can you add some data sample, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: `df.loc[df.column_name >= value,['column_name_1','column_name_2']] = value` is one way to replace multiple columns in one go. If you have a lot of columns consider looking at [`df.columns.difference()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: See second answer on marked dup.

Comment: @jpp Or the third answer there :-)

Comment: @coldspeed, Nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.loc[:,column_name] = np.where(df.column_name > 1, 1, df.column_name)
```

I am guessing you want 0 and 1 in you column, alternatively you can do:

```
df.loc[:,column_name] = np.where(df.column_name !=0, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a lambda function and np.where()?

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: np.where(x > 1, 1, x))
```

Original dataframe:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col1000
0     1     2     1        1
1     0     3     1        1
2     0     1     0        1
3     1     1     0        0
4     2     1     2        2
5     1     0     2        2
6     2     0     4        4
7     2     2     1        4
8     1     2     1        2
```

After using lambda function:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col1000
0     1     1     1        1
1     0     1     1        1
2     0     1     0        1
3     1     1     0        0
4     1     1     1        1
5     1     0     1        1
6     1     0     1        1
7     1     1     1        1
8     1     1     1        1
```